# What is the difference between UIAlertActionStyleDestructive and UIAlertActionStyleCancel?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller

UIAlertActionStyleDestructive and UIAlertActionStyleCancel seem very similar to me. According to the documentation:

> UIAlertActionStyleCancel:
>   Apply a style that indicates the action cancels the operation and leaves things unchanged.

and

> UIAlertActionStyleDestructive:
>   Apply a style that indicates the action might change or delete data.

Regardless of style, the action will still have a completion handler, in which you can do whatever you see fit. Is the existence of both "destructive" and "cancel" for organizational purposes only, or is there some greater functional purpose served by having both options?

Comment: Why don't you create an action sheet with each of the available button styles and see what you get?

Comment: So that next time anyone else wonders about this, they can just refer to this SO post.

Comment: Try it, then you could see the difference. Its all about classic vs bold text vs red colored text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Destructive buttons usually styled by having bright red background, while cancel buttons will be regular gray buttons.